# Scraping Excel File and read on the fly

Tags: python, dataframe, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to get an Excel file from a website (https://rigcount.bakerhughes.com/na-rig-count), download and save it into memory to read it with Pandas. The file is an .xlsb with more than 700,000 lines.

With the code I'm using, I am able to get only 1457 rows... I tried to play with the chunksize but it didn't work.

Here is my code:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import os
import pandas as pd
from io import BytesIO, StringIO 

url = "https://rigcount.bakerhughes.com/na-rig-count"
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
link_temp = soup.find_all('div', attrs={'class': 'file-link'})

for i in link_temp:
    if 'Rig Count Pivot Table' in i.find().text:
        link = i
        break
    
href = link.a.get('href')

response = requests.get(href)

#Store file in memory
f = BytesIO()

for line in response.iter_content():
    f.write(line)
    
f.seek(0)

pd.read_excel(f, engine='pyxlsb', sheet_name = 1, skiprows=0)
```

I tried to save it locally and open it back, but there is an issue with the encoding that I haven't been able to solve.

Thanks for you help ! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```py
import trio
import httpx
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
from functools import partial


async def main(url):
    async with httpx.AsyncClient(timeout=None) as client:
        r = await client.get(url)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')
        tfile = soup.select_one('.file-link:-soup-contains(Table)').a['href']
        async with client.stream('GET', tfile) as r:
            fname = r.headers.get('content-disposition').split('=')[-1]
            async with await trio.open_file(fname, 'wb') as f:
                async for chunk in r.aiter_bytes():
                    await f.write(chunk)

        df = await trio.to_thread.run_sync(partial(pd.read_excel, fname, sheet_name=3, engine="pyxlsb"))
        print(df)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    trio.run(main, 'https://rigcount.bakerhughes.com/na-rig-count')
```

Output:

```
              Country      County        Basin DrillFor  ... Week RigCount State/Province  PublishDate
0       UNITED STATES      SABINE  Haynesville      Gas  ...   13        1      LOUISIANA        40634    
1       UNITED STATES  TERREBONNE        Other      Oil  ...   13        1      LOUISIANA        40634    
2       UNITED STATES   VERMILION        Other      Gas  ...   13        1      LOUISIANA        40634    
3       UNITED STATES   VERMILION        Other      Gas  ...   13        1      LOUISIANA        40634    
4       UNITED STATES        EDDY      Permian      Oil  ...   13        1     NEW MEXICO        40634    
...               ...         ...          ...      ...  ...  ...      ...            ...          ...    
769390  UNITED STATES        KERN        Other      Oil  ...   29        1     CALIFORNIA        44393    
769391  UNITED STATES        KERN        Other      Oil  ...   29        1     CALIFORNIA        44393    
769392  UNITED STATES        KERN        Other      Oil  ...   29        1     CALIFORNIA        44393    
769393  UNITED STATES        KERN        Other      Oil  ...   29        1     CALIFORNIA        44393    
769394  UNITED STATES        KERN        Other      Oil  ...   29        1     CALIFORNIA        44393    

[769395 rows x 13 columns]
```

<s>>Note: Seems you reached a bug within `pyxlsb` reader. Reading the sheet using index is the reason but using `sheet_name='Master Data'` is works fine.</s>

**Update**:

> the problem is that the excel file has 2 hidden sheets, and the 2nd sheets really has 1457 rows, the Master Data is actually the 4th sheet, so sheet_name=3 will work

**Last update**:

In order to follow [Python DRY Principle](https://realpython.com/lessons/dry-principle/) . I noticed that we don't need to save the file locally, or even visualize a file and store to the memory, and then load it to pandas.

Actually the `response` content itself stored into the memory, so we can load it all at once by passing `r.content` directly to pandas!

Use the below code:

```
import trio
import httpx
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
from functools import partial


async def main(url):
    async with httpx.AsyncClient(timeout=None) as client:
        r = await client.get(url)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')
        tfile = soup.select_one('.file-link:-soup-contains(Table)').a['href']
        r = await client.get(tfile)
        df = await trio.to_thread.run_sync(partial(pd.read_excel, r.content, sheet_name=3, engine="pyxlsb"))
        print(df)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    trio.run(main, 'https://rigcount.bakerhughes.com/na-rig-count')
```

Comment: Interesting. Thanks for adding some explanation.

Comment: @QHarr after investigating `pyxlsb`, i noticed it's not a bug. check updated answer.

Comment: Is there an actual sheet name? That would seem more robust than an index if the 3 is an index. Does the arg allow for passing a string literal?

Comment: @QHarr you can read it via `sheet_name=3` or `sheet_name="Master Data"`

Comment: @QHarr also you could do something like `x = pd.ExcelFile(fname)` and then `x.sheet_names` which will output `['Current Week Summary', 'Current Week Summary Data', 'Master Data Pivot', 'Master Data']`

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. I totally forgot to check if there was not hidden sheet!

Comment: `soup.select_one('.file-link:-soup-contains(Table) > a ')['href']` ? - seems cleaner if applies.

Comment: @QHarr Yes, but i shorten it based on the patterns within the site.

Comment: @αԋɱҽԃαмєяιcαη I tried also to read straight the response content (without any storage) but I hade a reponse 3XX or 4XX doing like this. But I didn't try with a user agent!

Comment: in case if you are trying to read it with pandas directly like `pd.read_html(url)` ---> in some cases the receiver DNS block the default User-Agent for requests which is `python-requests/2.25.1`.

Comment: @QHarr you deleted the room?

Comment: @αԋɱҽԃαмєяιcαη No. Frozen through lack of visitors :-(

Comment: @αԋɱҽԃαмєяιcαη Had you noticed this error? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68894819/httpx-module-httpcore-has-no-attribute-timeoutexception

Comment: @QHarr old bug!

Comment: @αԋɱҽԃαмєяιcαη I was surprised to see it appear with my scripts where I have httpx 0.22.0