# httpx - module 'httpcore' has no attribute 'TimeoutException'

Tags: python, http, python-requests, timeout, httpx

whenever I import the module "httpx", for example in this code:

```
import httpx

input()
```

I get this error:

```
module 'httpcore' has no attribute 'TimeoutException'
  line 1, in <module>
    import httpx
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might need to stick with an older version of httpx for now, try version 19

```
pip install httpx==0.19.0
```

Answer (score 1):

What version of pip are you using ?
Try updating pip and reinstalling the package
Or you can try installing the pre 10 release using
$ pip install httpx --pre
as stated in the httpx docs
https://www.python-httpx.org/

Comment: I installed httpcore[http2] and it worked

Comment: Please phrase this as an explained conditional answer, in order to avoid the impression of asking a clarification question instead of answering (for which a comment should be used instead of an answer, compare https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead ). For example like "If your problem is ... then the solution is to .... because .... ."

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I finally solved the error after 1 month, all you got to do is:

```
pip uninstall httpcore
```

then

```
pip install httpcore[http2]
```